# Looking for how to upload a directory and its contents using SFTP

Tags: php, phpseclib

I am building a PHP script that will take certain directories from a local server and upload them to a remote server. I am using phpseclib to work on this. I am trying to think of a recursive function that will upload the files one at a time. Currently I am using an array like so:

```
[14842] => Array
    (
        [0] => adlcp_rootv1p2.xsd
        [attachments] => Array
            (
            )

        [1] => icon_online_training.png
        [2] => icon_online_training_10_10.png
        [3] => icon_online_training_5_5.png
        [4] => ims_xml.xsd
        [5] => imscp_rootv1p1p2.xsd
        [6] => imsmanifest.xml
        [7] => imsmd_rootv1p2p1.xsd
        [8] => index_lms.html
        [9] => index_lms_html5.html
        [10] => ioslaunch.html
        [lms] => Array
            (
                [0] => AICCComm.html
                [1] => AICCFunctions.js
                [2] => API.js
            )
        [11] => meta.xml
        [mobile] => Array
            (
                [0] => 5WVFAZ5mwdE_80_DX492_DY492_CX170_CY246.png
                [1] => 5WVFAZ5mwdE_80_DX492_DY492_CX170_CY246.swf
                [2] => 5WWiJ1xMpse_80_DX800_DY800_CX400_CY193.png
                [slides] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 5VCMBOzQqNC.gz
                        [1] => 5VCMBOzQqNC.js
                        [2] => 5ZyGS2LfXQu.gz
                        [3] => 5ZyGS2LfXQu.js
                    )
                [56] => spinner.png
                [57] => storyline_compiled.js
            )

        [12] => story.html
        [13] => story.swf
        [story_content] => Array
            (
                [0] => 5WVFAZ5mwdE_80_DX492_DY492.swf
                [1] => 5WWiJ1xMpse_80_DX800_DY800.swf
                [2] => 5YBVUTyceKY_80_DX380_DY380.swf
                [3] => 5eOmKqzCtjp_80_B-30_C-40_RB_P_0_0_830_888_DX610_DY610.swf
                [4] => 5kmpqRdjAji_80_DX716_DY716.jpg
                [5] => 5mWp2jb2eV7_80_DX330_DY330.swf
                [6] => 5qT54mLzsgr_80_DX660_DY660.jpg
                [slides] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 5VCMBOzQqNC.swf
                        [1] => 5ZyGS2LfXQu.swf
                        [2] => 5cf9K2RD4e2.swf
                        [3] => 5kTbjeZczQg.swf
                    )

                [33] => story.js
                [34] => thumbnail.jpg
            )
        [14] => story_html5.html
        [15] => story_unsupported.html
    )

[6703] => Array
    (
        [0] => a day in the life of a rsa.docx
        [attachments] => Array
            (
            )

        [1] => icon_resources.png
        [2] => icon_resources_10_10.png
        [3] => icon_resources_5_5.png
    )
```

I will loop through the first part of the array for the top level of each directory. From there I would like to use a function that is going to recursively add files to a remove server where the keys that are arrays are the directory name and the array is the contents of that directory. A couple of examples from the first array in the list would be something like this:

```
/local/public_html/14842/adlcp_rootv1p2.xsd => /remote/public_html/14842/adlcp_rootv1p2.xsd
```

or

```
/local/public_html/14842/mobile/slides/5VCMBOzQqNC.gz => /remote/public_html/14842/mobile/slides/5VCMBOzQqNC.gz
```

To build that array I currently have a function that I may be able to modify so that is uploads the files rather than build a file but have had some trouble. Here is that loop and function for that:

```
foreach($cids as $c) {
    $dirArray[$c] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $c);
}

function dirToArray($dir)
{
$result = array();

$cdir = scandir($dir);
foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($value, array(".", ".."))) {
        if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)) {
            $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
        } else {
            $result[] = $value;
        }
    }
}

return $result;
}
```

If I need any more information to provide for assistance please let me know.

Comment: Exactly HOW is this not working? "had some trouble" doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: What i have currently is working is working. What I am trying to do is set up the function that will move the files over but I can't figure out how I would need to modify the dirToArray function so that is will be able to upload the directories and files instead.

Comment: note that you don't "upload" directories. a directory is just a container. you CREATE a directory on the remote system, and then upload files to place in that directory.

Comment: that might be where I was going then. I was trying to use $sftp->put() to transfer a directory. I am guessing if the directory doesn't exist, it will just create it when i do something like /home/public_html/dir/local.file.

Comment: Given your second question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/38361843/569976) is this something you still need help with?